# How can I create public function for Intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a RecyclerView that I give OnItemClickListener then open a new activity

```
private TextView Judul, Sub;
        private ImageView Gambar;
        private RelativeLayout ListItem;
        private Context context;
private String[] komposisi;
    private String[] kemasan;
    private String[] caraPakai;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Resources res = itemView.getResources();
            Judul = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memetitle);
            Sub = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_meme);
            Gambar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.meme);
            komposisi = res.getStringArray(R.array.ikomposisi);
            kemasan = res.getStringArray(R.array.ikemasan);
            caraPakai = res.getStringArray(R.array.iCara_Pakai);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            ListItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_list);
ListItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    int i = getAdapterPosition();
                    int a = R.drawable.comingsoon;

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Detail.class);
                        intent.putExtra("komposisi", komposisi[i]);
                        intent.putExtra("kemasan", kemasan[i]);
                        intent.putExtra("pakai", caraPakai[i]);

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("gambar", memeList.get(i));
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);

                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
```

and in other activitiy it also requires an Intent with some intent.putExtra, and I think I should make a public function for the Intent which will only call detail()

```
ListItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        detail()
                     }
}
```

the question is how to make the function detail()
Sorry if my question is confusing, and hopefully you understand my question, thank you very much

Comment: You shouldn't use a public function for this purpose firstly. Secondly if you make a public function how are you going to get the text from Judal and Sub in the other class? Still if you want to make a public function for this add parameters to the function. Parameters will be the items you are trying to send using intent. I hope you understand. If you still want a coded solution let me know.

Comment: read https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Answer (score 0):

you can just add in your activity

```
 public void detail(){
 //some codes here

        int i = getAdapterPosition();
        int a = R.drawable.comingsoon;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Detail.class);
        intent.putExtra("komposisi", komposisi[i]);
        intent.putExtra("kemasan", kemasan[i]);
        intent.putExtra("pakai", caraPakai[i]);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("gambar", memeList.get(i));
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        context.startActivity(intent);

 }
```

Comment: I'm confused to saying it :D

Comment: cant use Context on Intent, if use public void detail()

Comment: You get `Context` from the `Activity` itself using something like `context = this;`.